# Spinner with only month and year in Android

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

One of the requirements in my app is a `DatePickerDialog` that shows only the month and year without the day.

This is my code :

```
   //define format of YYYYMMDD
    private final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_salary);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                SupportedDatePickerDialog dpd = new SupportedDatePickerDialog(this, R.style.SpinnerDatePickerDialogTheme, new SupportedDatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(@NonNull DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                        String date = LocalDate.of(year, month+1, day).format(dtf);
                        textView.setText(date);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                dpd.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm using a 3rd party library from Ibotta because I only want to show a `Spinner` and not a `Calendar` when choosing a date.
 Everything else I tried was either deprecated or didn't work properly.

I was wondering if it is possible to reconfigure this piece of code so that the `DatePickerDialog` will only show the `Month` and `Year` without the `Day` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this library

Click [here](https://github.com/ma7madfawzy/dialogPlus)
and then you can use MonthDayPicker

```
new DialogPlusBuilder().blurBackground()
                       .buildMonthDayPickerDialog(Calendar.getInstance(),
                    (pickedMonth, pickedDay) ->{ //TODO implement your business}
                       .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Month Day Picker");
```